# 1990s BBS game featuring mining elements from a planet

Tags: history, gaming, identify-this-game, bbs

Sometime in the 90s (sorry, can't be more specific) I used to dial in to a BBS and play a multi-player game that involved manually mining elements from a planet. It was very detailed, you got employed by a company and even got assigned quarters and had to spend the money you made from mining in order to buy food, clothing and other items.  There was a whole mining complex you could navigate with shops and restaurants. I remember lots of players being online and it had a very active chat that you could participate in while mining. I think there was even a live marketplace with active commodity pricing for the minerals you mined.

It's been killing me for days. I tried searching old bbs lists and even pulled out an old hard drive I kept from the system I might have used at the time to see if I could extract the phone number from the dialer logs, but it failed during read. Any thoughts? I would love to find it running somewhere and play it again, but mostly I just need the name so I can find info about it for something I am writing.

You were planet bound in the game, no ships. Ascii art graphics only, I think.

Comment: Maybe [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_BBS_door_games) will spur your memory. Perhaps [this one](https://www.giantbomb.com/bbs-door-game/3015-2520/games/) too.

Comment: Thank you, I found those lists and many others during my initial search. For some reason it isn't on any of them. I think it was a dedicated bbs, not a distributed game.

Comment: It might be helpful to note the state that the BBS was located in; I dialed into many BBSes in central CT in the 90’s and even ran one (TAG based), but I never heard of a game like this.

Comment: Also, if there were “lots of players online” [simultaneously, I assume], and this was not a distributed game, it seems to me that it must have been on a computer more powerful than a PC. Could it be that you were actually dialing into a University system? Some of those did host games occasionally.

Comment: Not sure what the state was. It was definitely long distance for me. Could very well have been a uni system.  The actual bbs was dedicated to this game, there were no other options as I recall.

Comment: The only games I recall from this era where there was more than one type of element to mine was the original Pax Imperia on the Mac, and VGA Planets on the PC. The latter included a play-by-email option that did work over BBS mail. But I don't think Planets having the level of walking around you're describing.

Comment: The large number of online users suggests a mainframe host, and given the VGA-style graphics, perhaps Prodigy? I never used the system and can't find any sort of good list of its games.

Answer (score -1):

Are you thinking of TRADEWARS perhaps?

Comment: Could you provide some details of TRADEWARS, for comparison?

Comment: Tradewars does not match the description provided. Amongst other details, TW was not a synchronous multiplayer game and did not have any real time interactions or chats between the dial-up players.

Comment: No. I used to play TW, too. Different game.